# ionic 3: Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

App is not running on iPhone 6:

```
2018-03-14 17:34:07.590225+0530 eppm[357:20646] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/32ECC5FE-CFFD-4E77-AB78-B42F3D219CD8/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2018-03-14 17:34:10.660950+0530 eppm[357:20646] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
2018-03-14 17:34:10.661243+0530 eppm[357:20646] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-03-14 17:34:10.688928+0530 eppm[357:20646] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-03-14 17:34:10.794150+0530 eppm[357:20646] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-03-14 17:34:10.794353+0530 eppm[357:20646] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-03-14 17:34:10.803403+0530 eppm[357:20646] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-03-14 17:34:10.803501+0530 eppm[357:20646] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-03-14 17:34:10.804193+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][console] 0.162005ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.804427+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.152946ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.808913+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 4.420042ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.809187+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.169039ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.809441+0530 eppm[357:20646] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2018-03-14 17:34:10.813333+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 3.888011ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.839537+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 26.057959ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.857581+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 17.849088ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.863205+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][file] 5.441070ms
2018-03-14 17:34:10.863303+0530 eppm[357:20646] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 59.348941ms
2018-03-14 17:34:32.344058+0530 eppm[357:20646] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.
```

Device Info

```
Error:  Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.
Device: iPhone 6
iOS version: 11.2.6
```

Ionic Info

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.1
npm        : 5.5.1
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

The same build is working on following devices:

```
iPhone 4s - iOS v9.3.6
Samsung On Nxt - Android Nougat - 7.0
Motorola G5s Plus - Android Nougat - 7.1
```

Comment: What command are you using to run your app?
Are you using LIVERELOAD option?

Comment: @HumbertodeCarvalho yes, I'm using this command:
ionic cordova run ios -lc --debug --device

Comment: Without the livereload, it’s working?

Comment: No. I tried these many options: `ionic cordova run ios --prod`, `ionic cordova run ios -c --debug --device` and `ionic cordova build ios` and even tried running app from xCode later on but no luck.

Also checked in safari web inspector and it kept saying Failed to load resources.

Comment: Did you get the solution?